# Flutter Dependent Dropdown Error "Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

Good day.
I am encountering a problem wherein I get an error `Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value`  **when selecting back the default value of the parent dropdown.**

For Example:
`"Product" is the default value in dropdown and click both "Meal" and "Health" by swapping. I'll select now the "Services" and select both "Massage" and "Delivery" by swapping. Now, will go to "Product" then the error will be visible.`

These are the variables that I used.

```
String? getStringType;
String? getStringCategory;
List<dynamic> dropDownItemType = [];
List<dynamic> categoryMasters = [];
List<dynamic> categories = [];
String? itemTypeId;
String? categoryId;
```

and here is my initState where the List Values are stored.

```
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    dropDownItemType.add({"id": 1, "name": "Product"});
    dropDownItemType.add({"id": 2, "name": "Services"});

    categoryMasters = [
      {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Meal",
        "ParentId": 1,
      },
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Health",
        "ParentId": 1,
      },
      {
        "ID": 3,
        "Name": "Massage",
        "ParentId": 2,
      },
      {
        "ID": 4,
        "Name": "Delivery",
        "ParentId": 2,
      },
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is my Parent Dropdown where the Child Dropdown depends on what value is going to be selected.

```
FormHelper.dropDownWidget(
                                context,
                                "Select Type",
                                this.itemTypeId,
                                this.dropDownItemType,
                                (onChangedVal) {
                                  itemTypeId = onChangedVal;
                                  getStringType = dropDownItemType[
                                          int.parse(itemTypeId.toString()) - 1]
                                      ["name"];

                                  print(
                                      "ge: ${itemTypeId} and ${getStringType}");
                                  this.categories = this
                                      .categoryMasters
                                      .where((categoryItem) =>
                                          categoryItem["ParentId"].toString() ==
                                          onChangedVal.toString())
                                      .toList();
                                  setState(() {
                                    this.categoryId = null;
                                  });
                                },
                                (onValidateVal) {
                                  if (onValidateVal == null) {
                                    return 'Select a Type';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                borderFocusColor: const Color(0xFFCECECE),
                                prefixIconColor: const Color(0xFF808080),
                                borderColor: const Color(0xFFCECECE),
                                enabledBorderWidth: 1,
                                prefixIconPaddingLeft: 12,
                                borderRadius: 12,
                                paddingLeft: 0,
                                hintFontSize: 12,
                                paddingRight: 0,
                                contentPadding: 14,
                                showPrefixIcon: true,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.type_specimen),
                              ),
```

and this is the child dropdown wherein it depends on the parent dropdown's value.

```
FormHelper.dropDownWidget(
                              context,
                              "Select Category",
                              this.categoryId,
                              this.categories,
                              (onChangedVal) {
                                this.categoryId = onChangedVal;
                                setState(() {
                                  this.categoryId = this
                                      .categoryMasters[0]["ParentId"]
                                      .toString();
                                });
                                getStringCategory = this.categoryMasters[
                                        int.parse(categoryId.toString()) - 1]
                                    ["Name"];
                                print("Cat Name: ${getStringCategory}");
                                
                              },
                              (onValidateVal) {
                                return null;
                              },
                              borderFocusColor: const Color(0xFFCECECE),
                              prefixIconColor: const Color(0xFF808080),
                              borderColor: const Color(0xFFCECECE),
                              enabledBorderWidth: 1,
                              prefixIconPaddingLeft: 12,
                              hintFontSize: 12,
                              borderRadius: 12,
                              paddingLeft: 0,
                              paddingRight: 0,
                              contentPadding: 14,
                              showPrefixIcon: true,
                              borderWidth: 1,
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.type_specimen),
                              
                            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, i have reference of dropdown list please refer it:

```
class _EmptySearchState extends State<EmptySearch> {
  String? value1 = "";

  List<String> nameList = [
    "Name1",
    "Name2",
    "Name3",
    "Name4",
    "Name5",
    "Name6",
    "Name7",
    "Name8"
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    value1 = nameList[0];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 2.0,
        title: const Text('Hello'),
      ),
      body: DropdownButton(
        value: value1,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            value1 = value.toString();
          });
        },
        items: nameList.map(
          (item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              value: item,
              child: Text(item),
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]